# Testing omniauth hash format with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, bdd, omniauth, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write some tests for Omniauth integration. Specifically, I want to know if the format of the hash has changed from version to version if I upgrade.

I found the wiki (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) which shows that I can mockup an auth manually:

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
    'provider' => 'twitter',
    'uid' => '123545'
    # etc.
  }
```

...but I don't see this as helpful. I have to manually configure the hash to what I expect Omniauth's hash to return. This doesn't tell me if the hash that Omniauth is *actually* to return fits that format.

Am I missing something obvious here? How can I test if the format I'm expecting is *actually* what Omniauth plans to give me?